# NumberFormatException on empty Scala.js tests

Tags: scala, sbt, scala.js

One Scala.js project of mine always throws the following exception when trying to run `sbt test` (on the build server):

```
[info] Fast optimizing /opt/buildagent/work/4d5c5801308f9701/com.xxxx.cc.b/target/scala-2.12/yyyyy-zzzzzzzzz-test-fastopt.js
[11:42:23][Step 8/9] Fast optimizing /opt/buildagent/work/4d5c5801308f9701/com.xxxx.cc.b/target/scala-2.12/yyyyy-zzzzzzzzz-test-fastopt.js
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] Error
[11:42:38][Step 8/9]     at $c_jl_NumberFormatException.$c_jl_Throwable.fillInStackTrace__jl_Throwable (file:///opt/buildagent/work/4d5c5801308f9701/com.xxxx.cc.b/target/scala-2.12/yyyyy-zzzzzzzzz-test-fastopt.js:47356:14)
[11:42:38][Step 8/9]     at $c_jl_NumberFormatException.$c_jl_Throwable.init___T__jl_Throwable__Z__Z (file:///opt/buildagent/work/4d5c5801308f9701/com.xxxx.cc.b/target/scala-2.12/yyyyy-zzzzzzzzz-test-fastopt.js:47474:10)
[11:42:38][Step 8/9]     at $c_jl_NumberFormatException.init___T (file:///opt/buildagent/work/4d5c5801308f9701/com.xxxx.cc.b/target/scala-2.12/yyyyy-zzzzzzzzz-test-fastopt.js:154387:58)
[11:42:38][Step 8/9]     at $c_jl_Integer$.fail$1__p1__T__sr_Nothing$ (file:///opt/buildagent/work/4d5c5801308f9701/com.xxxx.cc.b/target/scala-2.12/yyyyy-zzzzzzzzz-test-fastopt.js:75485:43)
[11:42:38][Step 8/9]     at $c_jl_Integer$.parseInt__T__I__I (file:///opt/buildagent/work/4d5c5801308f9701/com.xxxx.cc.b/target/scala-2.12/yyyyy-zzzzzzzzz-test-fastopt.js:75490:10)
[11:42:38][Step 8/9]     at $c_Lcom_xxxx_cc_b_base_Bor$.$c_Lcom_xxxx_cc_b_core_base_BorBase.init___Lcom_xxxx_cc_b_core_pages_fleetViewPageBase_FleetViewPageBase__Lcom_xxxx_cc_b_core_guiElements_navbar_NavBarBase (file:///opt/buildagent/work/4d5c5801308f9701/com.xxxx.cc.b/target/scala-2.12/yyyyy-zzzzzzzzz-test-fastopt.js:4112:24)
[11:42:38][Step 8/9]     at $c_Lcom_xxxx_cc_b_base_Bor$.init___ (file:///opt/buildagent/work/4d5c5801308f9701/com.xxxx.cc.b/target/scala-2.12/yyyyy-zzzzzzzzz-test-fastopt.js:33487:169)
[11:42:38][Step 8/9]     at $m_Lcom_xxxx_cc_b_base_Bor$ (file:///opt/buildagent/work/4d5c5801308f9701/com.xxxx.cc.b/target/scala-2.12/yyyyy-zzzzzzzzz-test-fastopt.js:33811:69)
[11:42:38][Step 8/9]     at file:///opt/buildagent/work/4d5c5801308f9701/com.xxxx.cc.b/target/scala-2.12/yyyyy-zzzzzzzzz-test-fastopt.js:207467:10
[11:42:38][Step 8/9]     at file:///opt/buildagent/work/4d5c5801308f9701/com.xxxx.cc.b/target/scala-2.12/yyyyy-zzzzzzzzz-test-fastopt.js:207535:4
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] [error] org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$NonZeroExitException: Node.js with JSDOM exited with code 1
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] [error]    at org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$AbstractExtRunner.waitForVM(ExternalJSEnv.scala:126)
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] [error]    at org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$AsyncExtRunner$$anon$1.$anonfun$run$2(ExternalJSEnv.scala:191)
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] [error]    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] [error]    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] [error]    at org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$AsyncExtRunner$$anon$1.run(ExternalJSEnv.scala:191)
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] ObjectEvent(error, TraceEvent(Error, org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$NonZeroExitException: Node.js with JSDOM exited with code 1, None, None), None, None, sbt.internal.util.TraceEvent, JObject([Lsjsonnew.shaded.scalajson.ast.unsafe.JField;@72a33316))
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] [error] (Test / loadedTestFrameworks) org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$NonZeroExitException: Node.js with JSDOM exited with code 1
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] (Test / loadedTestFrameworks) org.scalajs.jsenv.ExternalJSEnv$NonZeroExitException: Node.js with JSDOM exited with code 1
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] [error] Total time: 22 s, completed Jun 26, 2019 11:42:38 AM
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] Process exited with code 1
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] Process exited with code 1 (Step: run scala unit tests (Simple Build Tool (Scala)))
[11:42:38][Step 8/9] Step run scala unit tests (Simple Build Tool (Scala)) failed
```

The peculiar thing is that this project does not even have any tests specified. The build-server builds all projects in the same manner, so I cannot just deactivate the `sbt test` build step. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Does adding a dummy test sidestep the problem?

Comment: Looks like the `object com.xxxx.cc.b.base.Bor` is exported with `@JSExportTopLevel`, and that its parent constructor in `BorBase` throws the exception (by calling `Integer.parseInt` with an empty string). Top-level exported objects are instantiated before anything else happens in a Scala.js app, including before *detecting* whether there are tests or not.

Comment: @sjrd Thank your for the great input. This indeed resolved the problem! I had this line in the extended `BorBase` class: `org.scalajs.dom.window.location.port.toInt`, which failed when running the tests (and only failed in the projects with the `@JSExportTopLevel` annotation - that's why the core did not fail). If you write your comment as an answer, I can accept your solution.

Comment: Posted as an answer as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the object `com.xxxx.cc.b.base.Bor` is exported with `@JSExportTopLevel`, and that its parent constructor in `BorBase` throws the exception (by calling `Integer.parseInt` with an empty string). Top-level exported objects are instantiated before anything else happens in a Scala.js app, including before *detecting* whether there are tests or not.